# Modo subjuntivo "¿Porque seas mayor crees que puedes comportarte así?"

Tags: subjuntivo

Dos preguntas:

> ¿Porque **seas** mayor crees que puedes comportarte así?

1. ¿Me podríais explicar el uso del subjuntivo aquí? La causa no va negada, entonces por qué va con el subjuntivo?
2. ¿Cuál sería la traducción en inglés? 
   ("*Only because you think you are a grown-up you can behave like that?*" ¿Así?)

Comment: Almost there: "Only because you are a grown-up you think you can behave like that?"

Comment: ¡Perdonad! Solo quería asegurarme de que he entendido bien la frase. Por eso he añadido "you think" porque pensaba que así se podría explicar el subjuntivo (la otra persona se cree ser mayor pero en realidad no lo es... o algo por el estilo =)

Comment: @Charlie mejor aún sería con «just»: «Just because you're a grown-up …»

Comment: El problema es que hay un error en la frase. Debería ser "¿Por que seas mayor...?" Con el por que separado. Seguramente esto te ayudará a razonar el subjuntivo.

Comment: @FGSUZ No estoy de acuerdo. "Porque" debe ir unido en esta oración, pues introduce una causa. "por que" se escribe separado cuando la preposición "por" introduce una proposición nominal: *Lucharé por que entiendas mi causa.* (Lucharé por algo: que entiendas mi causa.)

Comment: Posibles traducciones: *You think you can behave like that just because you might be older than me?  You think you can behave like that because you're supposedly older than me?  You think you can behave like that just because you're "older" than me?* (Esta última con voz de comillas y sarcasmo para "older".)   Nota:  esta frase no necesariamente viene del hijo o hija.  Podría venir del gemelo que nació cinco minutos después del otro.

Comment: @aparente001 No creo que se cuestione que la otra persona sea mayor que el hablante. Lo que se cuestiona es que, por ser mayor (de edad o respecto del hablante, no queda claro), crea que pueda comportarse como se comporta.

Comment: @Gustavson - Ah.  ¿Entonces sería equivalente "Por ser mayor, ¿crees que puedes etc."?

Comment: @aparente001 Exactamente. Una buena paráfrasis sería: *¿Crees que por ser mayor **puedas** (o puedes) comportarte así?* Es curioso que el subjuntivo tienda a trasladarse al otro verbo.

Comment: @Gustavson - gracias.

Comment: **Just because** you're an adult, you think etc.

Answer (score 4):

Bien por la traducción de Charlie/Guifa.

Me concentraré en la respuesta al punto (1). En realidad, se trata de una pregunta retórica, que conlleva implícita una respuesta **negativa** de parte del propio hablante:

> a) ¿Porque seas mayor crees que puedes comportarte así? (Idea implícita: **No** porque seas mayor puedes comportarte así.)

Cabe agregar que el uso de subjuntivo es opcional. El indicativo también sería correcto:

> b) ¿Porque eres mayor crees que puedes comportarte así?

La diferencia (sutil) entre (a) y (b) es que (a) suena más descalificatoria, o más desafiante, puesto que el hablante presupone una respuesta negativa. En cambio, (b) puede sonar un poco más neutra. Tanto es así que la causal puede posponerse sin problemas en (b) (como ocurriría con cualquier causal) pero tiende a permanecer antepuesta en (a) (donde tiñe de negatividad a toda la oración desde el inicio):

a') ¿Crees que puedes comportarte así porque seas mayor? (rara)

b') ¿Crees que puedes comportarte así porque eres mayor? (normal)

Buscando en Internet, encontré que el tema es tratado en el libro "[El subjuntivo 2](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=x8uTBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=%22porque%20seas%22%20subjuntivo&source=bl&ots=TFAHOMaaDq&sig=ACfU3U3XxmKSuQbWOfpzsbUx0O7551Af6A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj95srQoPviAhWMJrkGHerUBVUQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22porque%20seas%22%20subjuntivo&f=false)" de Pilar Díaz Ballesteros, José Amenós Pons y María Luisa Rodríguez Sordo. Lamentablemente, la versión disponible para lectura es acotada, pero creo que lo que se alcanza a leer es suficiente para ratificar mis dichos:

[image: Ejemplos similares]

Transcribo los ejemplos encontrados por si se pierde el vínculo:

> Ahora mismo me voy al cine. Vamos a ver... en el Princesa ponen una película argentina, de esas que no le gustan nada a Miguel porque, según él, son demasiado románticas... ¿Románticas las películas argentinas? ¡Qué barbaridad! ¡Porque él lo **diga**! A mí me parecen muy humanas." Al recoger el abrigo, su teléfono móvil le avisa de la llegada de un mensaje. Es de su amiga Carmen, que le dice que va a venir a verla esa noche. Por unos momentos, Ana duda si salir o no... "¿Porque ella **quiera** venir voy a quedarme aquí esperándola? ¡No! Hablaré con ella por teléfono," piensa mientras cierra la puerta de su casa.

[image: Explicación]

Y esta es la explicación que dan los autores:

> En oraciones interrogativas como "¿Porque ella quiera venir voy a quedame en casa?", "¿Y porque seas mi hermano mayor, tienes razón?"... el hablante cuestiona que el hecho introducido por "porque" sea la causa de lo que dice. [...]
>
> En oraciones exclamativas como "¡Porque tú lo mandes!", "¡Porque ella quiera!", "¡Porque vosotros lo digáis!"... mostramos que no estamos de acuerdo con los pensamientos o con las intenciones de alguien.
>
> En todas estas oraciones, el verbo de la oración subordinada está en el subjuntivo.
>
> Nota. Las oraciones exclamativas del tipo "¡Porque tú lo mandes!" son propias de la lengua oral en situaciones informales.

A raíz de un intercambio con @aparente001 en la sección de comentarios correspondiente a la pregunta, acabo de descubrir que, si la causal se vuelve infinitiva, el subjuntivo tiende a trasladarse al otro verbo para transmitir el significado negativo del que hablábamos:

- ¿Crees que por ser mayor **puedas** comportarte así? (Idea subyacente: No creo que puedas comportarte así aun siendo mayor.)

En cambio, el uso del indicativo vuelve la pregunta neutra:

- ¿Crees que por ser mayor puedes comportarte así?

Comment: Igual en este caso la sustitución ayuda un poco.  En la conjunción *porque*, efectivamente estamos diciendo *a causa de que*, y me parece que en tal construcción sale más evidente la razón por el (no) uso del subjuntivo.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! ¿Me podrías decir por favor si he entendido bien? Entonces, ¿es la semántica de la frase que causa el uso del subjuntivo y no la sintaxis?

Comment: Me alegra que la respuesta te haya servido.En realidad, todos los modos verbales están asociados a un significado. Existen casos en que ciertas estructuras inducen u obligan al uso de un determinado modo pero, en el fondo, en general siempre hay una razón de sentido. Esto se observa más claramente cuando hay alternancia entre dos modos, como expliqué en mi respuesta. Otro ejemplo típico es: *Aunque llueva, iré* (Even if it rains, which may or may not be case, I'll go) and *Aunque llueve, iré* (It does rain, but I'll go all the same).